# Free Cross Browser Testing Tool

Tags: web-development, web-browser, web

I am looking for a free cross browser testing tool, such that I can run my website (preferably localhost too) on different browsers versions (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.)

I found browserStack and Lambdatest, they are exactly what I was looking for. Except that they are paid services. I did some research, and almost all of them are paid services. Are there any free cross browser testing tool you guys have used?

Comment: "cross browser testing tool", I think it is a very expressive terminology. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your requirements, I think you can take benefit from the freemium plan offered by LambdaTest which includes 60 mins/month of Realtime Browser Testing, 100 minutes of automation testing, and more.

Other than that I think you can use Katalon which is a free cross-browser testing tool.

Comment: I just tried Katalon, looks like they do not support Safari spy. Only Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Edge

Comment: Then I would suggest trying the Freemium plan of LambdaTest. It does have browsers like Safari, Yandex and IE as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question I think you can use Comparium. It supports browsers from different platforms, and it provides offline reports of website test results by e-mail, supports parallel creation of screens with the same interface. It is cost-effective and time-saving. You can access all features from one spot using Comparium. It is also available as a mobile version.

You can also use Lambda Test, BrowserStack, Spoon, Selenium as cross-browser testing tools depending on your need. However, they are not entirely free.

Comment: running Safari on Comparium is considered a pro feature :(

Answer (score 0):

I use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/).

Selenium components "webdriver" and "Selenium remote control" take care of translating and sending these actions to your browser.

They also offer the free "Selenium IDE" tool, which used to be a simple "macro recorder". Selenium IDE plays back your actions that you have recorded, e.g. a series of mouse clicks on a web page.

Browser vendors MS, Apple, Mozilla, Google all collaborate with the Selenium Project.

There are a lot of companies from the Selenium Ecosystem linked on the homepage. See "sponsors".